# NVIDIA driver problem after apt upgrade ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade

I have a problem after apt upgrade ang get this message:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libnvidia-ifr1-390 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 but it is not installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390:i386 but it is not installed
 nvidia-driver-390 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 (= 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-390:i386 (= 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

After that I try apt --fix-broken install, but I get:

```
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-gl-390'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-390:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so by libnvidia-gl-390'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-390:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I try solution from 
[how to fix this apt problem on ubuntu 18.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042929/how-to-fix-this-apt-problem-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb
```

then to erase all of the downloaded files in your cache.

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

And again I got:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libnvidia-ifr1-390 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 but it is not installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390:i386 but it is not installed
 nvidia-driver-390 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 (= 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-390:i386 (= 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I update ubuntu from version 16.04 to 18.04 3 weeks ago - but this problem appeared two days ago.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It most likely didn't install correctly.
I'd probably remove the packages without dependencies like so:

```
sudo dpkg -r libnvidia-ifr1-390
sudo dpkg -r libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386
sudo dpkg -r nvidia-driver-390
```

Using those commands should free up apt-get, now you can install the dependencies and reinstall the driver: (This should install the dependencies automatically)

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-390
```

And if the same thing happens again, try this: (This installs the listed dependencies and the driver)

```
sudo apt-get install libnvidia-gl-390:i386
sudo apt-get install libnvidia-gl-390
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-390
```

Or this: (This uninstalls and purges anything installed related to Nvidia and installs the driver while also deleting local copies of packages to download it again)

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-390
```

Comment: This can help - Thnx!!!!!!!!