# Ubuntu 18.04 broken install problem with libnvidia-common-450 package

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, dpkg

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on my workstation along with the recommended nvidia drivers, where I used `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to do so, and `ubuntu-drivers devices` recommends installing `nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free recommended`.

However, after installing the recommended driver, my package system is broken. When I try to update the software using the "Software updater", I get the following message:

> ```
> The package system is broken. Check if you are using third party
> repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of
> problems.
> Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
> Transaction failed: The package system is broken
>  The following packages have unmet dependencies: libnvidia-gl-450: Depends: libnvidia-common-450 but it is not installed
>                   Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.2) but 1:8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
> libnvidia-gl-450:i386: Depends: libnvidia-common-450 but it is not installed
> ```

A forced installation of the package using `sudo apt-get install -f libnvidia-common-450` yields the following error:

> ```
> dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-common-450_450.80.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb
> (--unpack):
>  trying to overwrite '/usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-450.80.02-key-documentation',
>  which is also in package libnvidia-common-450-server  450.80.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.3
>  Errors were encountered while processing:
>  /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-common-450_450.80.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
> ```

And nothing is resolved. Trying to reconfigure the package using `sudo dpkg --configure -a` says that the package `libnvidia-common-450 is not installed`. I'm not sure where to go next, and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try the solution here https://askubuntu.com/q/56761/26246 `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install -f libnvidia-common-450`

Comment: the same question and I have solved it by: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253784/cannot-purge-nvidia-drivers?newreg=a976a4de75734ce4a265affc5b7ec0d4

Comment: This is not 18.04 specific and happened on my Ubuntu 20.04 too.

Comment: Thanks for the comments; running `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install -f libnvidia-common-450` worked for me! For this problem, the solution posted on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253784/cannot-purge-nvidia-drivers?newreg=a976a4de75734ce4a265affc5b7ec0d4 didn't work for me...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**I solved this issue by using the the following command** to reinstall `libnvidia-common-450-server`:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install -f libnvidia-common-450-server
```

---

The problem started after following an online article to install nvidia drivers.  This was the error I was getting:

```
libnvidia-gl-450-server: Depends: libnvidia-common-450-server but it
is not installed Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.2) but
1:8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed libnvidia-gl-450-server:i386:
Depends: libnvidia-common-450-server but it is not installed
```

Comment: Worked for me, but had to change to `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install -f libnvidia-common-450`. What a lifesaver!

Comment: Thx a lot, that helped me too. Here is a related report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-450-server/+bug/1899522

Comment: Thank you so much; this worked for me too when I ran `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install -f libnvidia-common-450`. Interesting to learn that it is a bug - but this solution seems to work quite well. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 6):

Same issue. Also because of it could not update via Software updater and other issues installing lead to same dependency error. This fixed it for me too:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install -f libnvidia-common-450
```

Comment: That worked for me, thank you!

Comment: You could simply use `sudo apt autoremove libnvidia-common-450` and then install again.