# ubuntu-drivers autoinstall does not work due to broken packages

Tags: nvidia

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

```
root@Ubuntu19-04:~# ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-18.04-edge : Depends: linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.4.0-60-generic (= 5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1) but 5.4.0-60.67 is to be installed
                                                   Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-460 (<= 460.32.03-1) but it is not going to be installed
                                                   Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-460 (>= 460.32.03) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-driver-460 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-460 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-460 (<= 460.32.03-1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-460 (>= 460.32.03) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-460 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-extra-460 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-decode-460 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-460 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-utils-460 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-460 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-460 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-460 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-460:i386 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-460:i386 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-460:i386 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried `dpkg --configure -a` and `apt install -f` to no avail.

Comment: `apt-cache policy linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-18.04-edge` and `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try to install the dependencies manually, e.g. `sudo apt install linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.4.0-60-generic` and so on... after that run `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`.
2. If this does not work, uninstall all nvidia drivers and run `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` again.

Answer (score 0):

I used the answer to this question: [Ubuntu 18.04 broken install problem with libnvidia-common-450 package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285472/ubuntu-18-04-broken-install-problem-with-libnvidia-common-450-package)

But I swapped the package name from

```
libnvidia-common-450-server
```

To

```
nvidia-driver-460-server
```